# How to determine, in an app with several ViewControllers attached to NavigationControllers, what the currently displayed View is?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iOS 8 app, built with Objective-C, with a `TabBarController`, with 3 tabs. Each Tab links to a `NavigationController` (so there are 3 `NavigationController`s), and each `NavigationController` has a stack with several `ViewController`s in it.

So, at any given time, the app's user can be on, say, `ViewController` 2 of `NavigationController` 1 (which means Tab 1 is selected). And then hop to Tab 3 (`NavigationController` 3) and be seeing `ViewController` 1, say.

The question is, no matter which `ViewController` the app user is seeing (and therefore, no matter which `NavigationController` / `TabBar` Tab is in effect), how can I determine (i.e., get a pointer/reference to) which `ViewController` is being shown?

Do I need to get the `TabBarController`, get its array of `NavigationControllers`, then get the arrays of their of `ViewControllers`, and cycle through each element to see which is the top `ViewController`?

Or is there a short-cut way of determining which `ViewController` is being shown - and thereby get its parent `NavigationController` and thus Tab/`TabBar`? So, like, is there some "global" handle in iOS that points to the one view active and being displayed at any given time?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pretty close. From the tab controller, get the navigation controller from the selected tab. From the `UINavigationController`, simply use the `topViewController` property to get the currently displayed view controller.

```
UITabBarController *tabController = ... // a reference to the tab controller
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)tabController.selectedViewContrpller;
UIViewController *viewController = navController.topViewController;
```

Comment: Ah, OK. Seems simple enough. Thanks for the tip - appreciate it!